# Unable to get Child Categories inside <ul> using HtmlAgilityPack C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am new in Webscraping and trying to get data from a website with HTMLAgilityPack using ASP.NET C#. HTML structure which I am trying to parse is:

```
<li class='subsubnav' id='new-women-clothing'>
    <span class='cat-name'>CLOTHING</span>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="/womenswear/womens-just-in" id="just-in">Just In</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-exclusives" id="exclusives">Exclusives</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-dresses" id="dresses-&-gowns">Dresses & Gowns</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-coats" id="coats">Coats</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-jackets" id="jackets">Jackets</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-shirts-and-blouses" id="shirts-&-blouses">Shirts & Blouses</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-tops" id="tops">Tops</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-knitwear" id="knitwear">Knitwear</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-sweatshirts" id="sweatshirts">Sweatshirts</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-skirts-and-shorts" id="skirts-&-shorts">Skirts & Shorts</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-trousers" id="trousers">Trousers</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-jumpsuits" id="jumpsuits">Jumpsuits</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-jeans" id="jeans">Jeans</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-swimwear" id="swimwear">Swimwear</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-lingerie" id="lingerie">Lingerie</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/new-season-nightwear" id="nightwear">Nightwear</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/sportswear" id="sportswear">Sportswear</a></li>

        <li><a href="/womenswear/ski-wear" id="ski-wear">Ski Wear</a></li>

    </ul>

</li>
```

I am getting the parent categories which in this case is CLOTHING perfectly but i am unable to get elements inside ul.

here is my c# code:

```
var html = new HtmlDocument();
html.LoadHtml(new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.harrods.com/men/t-shirts?icid=megamenu_MW_clothing_t_shirts"));
var root = html.DocumentNode;
var nodes = root.Descendants();
var totalNodes = nodes.Count();
var dt = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("cat-name"));

foreach(var x in dt)
{
    foreach (var element in x.Descendants("ul"))
    {
        child_data.Add(new cat_childs(element.InnerText));
    }

    data.Add(new Categories(x.InnerText,child_data));
}

test.DataSource = data;
test.DataBind();
```

So how can I get the link and text of anchor tags inside `<ul>`?

Comment: The ul tag is not descendent of your span tag...

Comment: @FKutsche Alright so <ul> is actually the descendant of <li> am i right> ?

Comment: yes, could be something like that: var ul = root.SelectSingleNode("./li[@id='new-women-clothing']/ul");

Comment: Alright. Thanks let me try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to base the iteration on `span` with `class='cat-name'`, then the target `ul` relation to the `span` is *following sibling* instead of *descendant*. You can use `SelectNodes()` to get following sibling elements from current `span`, like so :

```
foreach (var x in dt)
{
    foreach (var element in x.SelectNodes("following-sibling::ul/li/a"))
    {
        child_data.Add(new cat_childs(element.InnerText));
    }

    data.Add(new Categories(x.InnerText,child_data));
}
```

**UPDATE :**

It *seems* that the actual problem is in `child_data` variable being declared outside the outer loop. It means that you're keep adding item to the same `child_data` instance. Try to declare it inside the outer loop, right after `foreach (var x in dt){`. Alternatively, you can write the entire codes as a LINQ expression, something like this :

```
var data = (from d in dt
            let child_data = x.SelectNodes("following-sibling::ul/li/a")
                              .Select(o => new cat_childs(o.InnerText))
                              .ToList()
            select new Categories(x.InnerText, child_data)
           ).ToList();
```

Comment: There is still a problem, it is getting the data but the problem now is that It is not adding the <ul> elements according to span instead it is adding all the next <ul> elements also.

Comment: @BilalAmjad looks like the actual problem is not about the XPath fetching wrong `ul` elements. It is about the same `child_data` being used to store all matched `ul` elements. See **UPDATE** section for suggested solution

Answer (score 1):

Using this xpath. It will get all the <li> that contain a <span> that has a class='cat-name'. After which it picks all the <a>s that are enclosed by <li>.

```
//If the span has no influence on what you want you can simply use: 
//HtmlNodeCollection hNC = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//ul/li/a");

HtmlNodeCollection hNC = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li/span[@class='cat-name']/parent::*/ul/li");
foreach (HtmlNode h in hNC)
{
    Console.Write(h.InnerText+" ");
    Console.WriteLine(h.GetAttributeValue("href", ""));
}
```